# How to find the best polynomial that fits the following function!

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, exponential-function

This is actually my first question in the math forum. I am trying to duplicate the attached polynomial using as fewer points as I could see picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkoCH.jpg). Furthermore, I need also to control the curvature such that P1 (moves up and down) is a movable point and P2 is a fixed point see picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw8Xy.jpg).

[Orginal Polynomial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkoCH.jpg)

[Schematic diagram of the required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw8Xy.jpg)

The point distribution of the polynomial are as below;

```
x       y
0.005   44.81839716
0.028   43.82844733
0.059   41.30393108
0.083   37.9860759
0.114   31.80662588
0.138   27.60547091
0.169   22.97499314
0.200   19.16200589
0.231   16.11724316
0.255   14.25948199
0.307   11.35062076
0.333   10.36567635
0.357   9.57967646
0.396   8.504148089
0.419   8.013775773
0.435   7.742658941
```

I fitted a fifth order polynomial, however, it required defining 6 points. What would be the smartest way to duplicate it and control the curvature as illustrated in the picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw8Xy.jpg). Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by fisting?

Comment: User, the title you typed in said "that fists the following function!" This is incorrect. Someone else edited it to "that fits the following function" which is correct.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't mean to do that typo. Thank you for fixing it

Comment: What do you mean "control the curvature" exactly? The picture doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry! I may have not explained correctly in my discerption. All I want to do is to fix P2 and allow P1 to move up and down. What I meant by "control the curvature" is to be able to control the polynomial as illustrated by the dashed line and the arrow. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: I don't understand, but Are you looking for a tool/method like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cahqdxeshd) or [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hycpcbwtbq)? where you can move the point to draw a line. Note that the first is [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and the second is [spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)). I ask this because they are example of methods used in graphic program, that is in same way similar what you are looking for.

Comment: Bezier requires defining more than three points to duplicate the polynomial. I want to use not more than three points.

Comment: Both look promising, but they require at least four points.

Comment: Hi User, to notify a your comment to a person tag he/she (es @MauroVanzetto). Please edit the question with the info _use not more than three points_ (I don't see it before). Note that Bézier curve and spline can be also with less points (see the liked pages and also this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation). Now spoken about interpolation I think you will use 3 points because with 2 you can obtain only a strait line. For the same reason piecewise interpolation is not an option, so we are talking of global interpolation. With 3 points you have got a 2 degree (continue)

Comment: polynomial, i.e a parabola. Now, if I understand, you have got 3 points, with P2 and P3 fixed, after you set P1 and calculate the interpolation. After you move P1 and new calculation and so on. But look your second imagine    you must consider that there is a further point between the extrema and with interpolation you force the function to pass for this point. With this you have no much flexibility (in my opinion), further you can only move P1 and after take the result of calculation. I.e. in my opinion  interpolation can be it too rigid as a method. (continue)

Comment: Try to evaluate this. Maybe methods that arise from computation geometric can be more suitable. Because these methods are born to handle such issues, es. curvature (of course this is not a precise argument, but just to give an idea :-))

Comment: Mauro, your suggest links, specifically the Bezier link has helped me resolve it. I have got what I was hoping to get using the Bezier curve. It is a great technique. Thank you very much for all the information that you have provided. Much appreciated! :))) Salute!